# How to make vscode extension support earlier version of vscode?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm trying to develop a VSCode extension.

I created a project according to the official tutorial and implemented some small functions. I packed it up and sent it to my friends to experience. However my friend couldn't install it because his VSCode version didn't meet the requirements.

Since the extension I developed doesn't use newer features, I hope to lower its VSCode version requirements so that my friends can install it normally.

What should I do?

Thanks

I tried changing `engines.vscode` in `package.json` to an earlier version, and `devDependencies.@types/vscode` to the same version. I can now package and friends can install this extension.

However, I can't get the tests to run properly. According to the error, the test was using the version of VSCode I was using instead of the version specified in `engines.vscode`. Is this the reason for not being able to run the tests? what should I do?

Comment: Find the same situation in issues of microsoft/vscode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190220

Comment: Manually renaming the `vscode-win32-x64-archive-1.81.1.tmp` directory to `vscode-win32-x64-archive-1.81.1` can temporarily resolve this issue.

> Note: If you have opened the project in VSCode, you need to close VSCode first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the following if found:

```
out
node_modules
.vscode-test
*.vsix
```

Then run `npm install` and try again.

Comment: thank you for your reply.

I tried doing what you suggested, still the same result.

See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190220